# Java 8 generics input type Function

Tags: generics, java-8

Can someone please explain the generic logic which is used in Java 8

```
public static <T, K, U>
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
    return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);
}
```

According to PECS rule producer extend and consumer super. But i am having difficulty to fit this logic into first param or second one of toMap which is keyMapper.

Comment: These functions *consume* `T`s (hence `? super T`) and *produce* keys or values (`? extends K` resp. `? extends U`), a canonical example of “producer extends and consumer super”…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General information about PECS**

You have to think about PECS that way:

> Producer `extends`

Let's say you have a `List<? extends Number>`. This list will *always* produce the type it is extending e.g. `Number`. But you don't exactly know which type, you just know the common super type of given list. Look at following example:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

List<? extends Number> nums = ints;
Number n = ints.get(0); // will be 1
```

We are creating a list of `Integer`s and then assign that to our other list `nums`. This works, because the value returned by `nums` will always be a `Number` or a subtype. In this case an `Integer`. You cannot add something to the list though. Because you don't know what *actual* list really is represented by `nums`. E.g. Trying to add a `long` to `nums` will fail. Because the real list only supports `Integer`s:

```
nums.add(1L); // compiler error
```

> Consumer `super`

This is just the other way around. Let's again say you have a list, e.g. `List<?
 super Number>`. The list will always accept `Number`s and its subtypes to be added to the list:

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();

List<? extends Number> nums = objs;
nums.add(1);
nums.add(2L);
nums.add(3F);
```

Because the actual list is `objs` which can accept any `Object` instances above works. Though when trying to add something different than `Number`s to `nums` the compiler will complain. Because it can't directly verify that the list really can accept the object:

```
nums.add("4"); // compiler error
objs.add("4"); // works still
```

Now the problem is that you don't really know what `list` you're adding your stuff to. Which makes it impossible to define a general behaviour to what should be returned when using a method like `get(0)`. So java handles this by just returning an `Object`:

```
Object o = nums.get(0);
```

Which is equivalent to::

```
Object o = objs.get(0);
```

---

**Answer to Question**

So when applied to your real question. `keyMapper` can accept any object which type is matching `T` and produces any object which type matches `K`. Again an example might put you in the right direction:

Let's say we use `String` for type `T` and `Number` for type `K` which gives us a parameter signature like: `Function<? extends String, ? super Number> keyMapper`.

Now we can use the stuff i've said above to play with this signature. Lets say we define a mapper from `Object` to `Long`:

```
Function<Object, Long> objToLong = (Object o) -> 1L;
```

This mapper then can be assigned to the signature of `keyMapper`:

```
Function<? extends String, ? super Number> keyMapper = objToLong;
```

Because `objToLong` can accept a `String` and produces a `Number`. The same can be said about the `valueMapper`.

I hope this really long answers helps you to understand `PECS` better :)